# Save Thumbnails on server

Tags: nautilus, thumbnails

Is there a way to save nautilus thumbnails on a NAS instead of ~/.cache/thumbnails?

I have multiple devices accessing a NAS and it takes very long to always generate the thumbnail images. I'm thinking of a solution like Thumbs.db in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

*WARNING* I have **NOT** tried this in real life, and it may confuse your thumbnail-using applications. Please use the `man` command to understand the commands before execution, and adapt them to your environment.

This is a command-line solution, to be run in a Terminal.

```
# Ensure no process has any thumbnails open
sudo lsof +D $HOME/.cache/thumbnails
# If there are any processes listed, either exit them, or
# Terminate them with SIGKILL
sudo lsof -t +D $HOME/.cache/thumbnails | xargs --no-run-if-empty sudo kill -9
# Create a directory on the NAS, owned by me, readable by Group and Other 
sudo mkdir --parents --mode=0755 /NAS/thumbnails
sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) /NAS/thumbnails/
sudo chmod 755 /NAS/thumbnails
# Populate the NAS
cp -r -v $HOME/.cache/thumbnails/* /NAS/thumbnails
# Hide $HOME/.cache/thumbnails, but keep a copy in case this doesn't work
mv $HOME/.cache/thumbnails $HOME/.cache/Local_thumbnails
# Now, create a symbolic link (man ln) as $HOME/.cache/thumbnails that points to /NAS/thumbnails
ln --symbolic /NAS/thumbnails $HOME/.cache/thumbnails
ls -ld $HOME/.cache/thumbnails
ls -lR $HOME/.cache/thumbnails
#
#
# **If it fails**
# If your GUI app doesn't work with symbolic links, undo this by
# Ensure no process has any thumbnails open
sudo lsof +D $HOME/.cache/thumbnails
# If there are any processes listed, either exit them, or
# Terminate them with SIGKILL
sudo lsof -t +D $HOME/.cache/thumbnails | xargs --no-run-if-empty sudo kill -9
# delete the link
rm $HOME/.cache/thumbnails
# put the old way back
mv $HOME/.cache/Local_thumbnails $HOME/.cache/thumbnails
# clean up the NAS
sudo rm -rf /NAS/thumbnails
```

Use at your own risk.

Comment: hmm, using this solution, I would also save thumbnails of local images on the server. Not really what I want